# discord.py member join voice channel

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

How can I create a channel that if someone joins it, bot will create a text channel. Here is my code:

```
@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member):
    guild = member.guild
    role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="@everyone")

    chan = await member.guild.create_text_channel(f"ticket - {member}")
    await chan.set_permissions(role, send_messages=False, read_messages=False, add_reactions=False, embed_links=False, attach_files=False, read_message_history=False, external_emojis=False)
    await chan.set_permissions(member, send_messages=True, read_messages=True, add_reactions=True, embed_links=True, attach_files=True, read_message_history=True, external_emojis=True)
```

I also want to make bot create this channel only if user join specific channel. Another thing I have to fix is making this script works only if member join voice channel, not leave, edit etc. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with

```
voice_channel = client.get(CHANNEL_ID)
try:
    while True:
        voice_channel.members[0]
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
        ...
except:
    ...
```

***But be careful!!*** This is a loop which will always run (with only a pause of 0.1 seconds) and will check the voice channel for members!